# How to get options text in select dropdown in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here, I need to get options text from the select dropdown and do some operations. But, I don't know where I missed. I am getting both the options text.
Here what I tried.

```js
$('#sel').change(function(){
    alert($(this).val());
   temp = $('#sel option:selected').text();
    alert("temp value " +temp);
    if(temp = "Option 1")
{
    alert("Option 1 is selected");
   //DO SOME OPERATIONS
}
 if(temp = "Option 2")
{
    alert("Option 2 is selected");
    //DO SOME OPERATIONS
}
}).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="sel" id="sel">
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
     <option value="2">Option 2</option
      <option value="3">Option 3</option
</select>
```

[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hs74sby1/1/)

Comment: $('#sel').change(function(){  
   alert($('#sel option:selected').text());  
});

Comment: Your code is syntactically wrong `option not closed` also in jQuery code you are asign value in temp not comparing value with temp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

temp = "Option 1" is mistaken expression

temp == "Option 1" or temp === "Option 1" is correct expression

See below

```
$('#sel').change(function(){
    alert($(this).val());
   temp = $('#sel option:selected').text();
    alert("temp value " +temp);
    if(temp === "Option 1")
{
    alert("Option 1 is selected");
   //DO SOME OPERATIONS
}
 if(temp === "Option 2")
{
    alert("Option 2 is selected");
    //DO SOME OPERATIONS
}
}).change();
```

Answer (score 1):

[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hs74sby1/2/)

```
$('#sel').change(function(){
    alert($(this).val());
   temp = $('#sel option:selected').text();
   alert("temp value " +temp);
   if(temp == "Option 1")
   {
       alert("Option 1 is selected");
   }
   if(temp == "Option 2")
   {
       alert("Option 2 is selected");
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

your comparative operators are incorrect, it should be

```
temp == "Option 1"
```

not

```
temp = "Option 1"
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hs74sby1/3/)

Also you should remove `.change();` at the end of your function if you don't want your code executing on page load.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `>` in two places:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="sel" id="sel">
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
     <option value="2">Option 2</option> <!-- here -->
      <option value="3">Option 3</option> <!--and here -->
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have used assignment operator. It should be `==` instead of `=`.

```
if (temp == "Option 1") {
    alert("Option 1 is selected");
}
if (temp == "Option 2") {
    alert("Option 2 is selected");
}
```

[**See updated fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/hs74sby1/4/)

Answer (score 1):

Try like this -

Html -

```
<select id='job_title'>
    <option value='' class='job' role=''>- Select -</option>
    <option value='1' class='job1' role='Accountant'>Accountant</option>
    <option value='2' class='job2' role='Dev. Support'>Dev. Support</option>
</select>

<br />
<input type='text' id='catch_value'>
```

jQuery -

```
$('#job_title').live('change', function(){
    var m = (this.value);
    var n = $('.job'+m).attr('role');
    $('#catch_value').val(n);
    return false;
});
```

Eg. - [Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/TPE9r/28/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#sel').change(function(){
    var temp = this[this.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
    if(temp == "Option 1") {
        alert("Option 1 is selected");
    }
    if(temp == "Option 2") {
        alert("Option 2 is selected");
    }
    if(temp == "Option 3") {
        alert("Option 3 is selected");
    }
});
```

Also add this `<option selected disabled>Options:</option>` to your select box in order to have all options available for the event.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/04euwxe8/3/)